# Test connection speed with Java

Tags: java

I have a Java server and Java client I'm interested is there any way to test with java the performance speed and the delay time between them?

I don't want to use the standard ping.

Comment: How exactly do you define "performance speed" and "delay time"? You could send a specific amount of bytes and echo them back and then measure the roundtrip, for example.

Comment: yes, something like that - uploading or downloading file for example.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how Effective it would be, but I think of this approach :

1. send some specific amount of data to server, from server send back the time the uploading is finished then calculate the time required to send the data. Result Will Be U/L time. Do the same for the D/L time. Request data from server, server should respond you with data along with the time the first bit was sent from the server. When All data is downloaded, calculate your D/L time. 
   Important thing to note here is, there may be the different instance of time, at server & client (& most possibly there would be), you need to Sync you time with the server time first.
2. send some specific amount of data to server, send back the data. Calculate the total time required. It will be your D/L + U/L time. Since the calculation would be at client only no time syncing is required here.